# Code with generics with super does not work as expected

Tags: java, generics, compiler-construction, type-conversion

I have the following code :

```
List<? super Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Number>();
numbers.add(new Integer(10));
Number object = numbers.get(0);  //this doesn't compile??

Object object = numbers.get(0);  //this does compile
```

Then if I do :

```
numbers.add(new Object()); //doesn't compile in contradiction to above statement
```

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Number object` doesn't work because the compiler doesn't know that `numbers` is a list of `Number`s - it only knows that it's a list of something that's a superclass of `Integer`. So it might be a list of `Object`s for example, in which case storing the result of `get` in a `Number` variable wouldn't work. Thus the compiler doesn't allow it.

`Object object` is allowed because storing the result of `get` in an `Object` variable always works because you can store anything in an `Object` variable.

The reason that `numbers.add( new Object() )` doesn't work is that you're only allowed to add `Object`s to `List<Object>`s, but `numbers` may very well be a `List<Integer>` or a `List<Number>` (and in fact it is the latter), so that's not allowed.

Basically you have to think of it like this: `numbers` may be a list of `Integer`s, a list of `Number`s or a list of `Object`s, so you're only allowed to perform those actions that would work on either one of those three.

Answer (score 4):

`List<? super Integer>` allows `numbers` to be a list of `Objects`, and not just a list of `Numbers` or a list of `Integers`:

```
List<? super Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Based purely on the compile-time type of `numbers`, the following can't be guaranteed to be typesafe and is therefore rejected:

```
Number object = numbers.get(0);  //this doesn't compile
```

Answer (score 1):

By declaring `List<? super Integer>`, you are saying that it can accept any object that is a super class of `Integer` which includes `Number` and `Object` as well . So you can add instances of `Number` and `Object` in that list so while retrieving from the list the most generic type i.e. `Object` is considered .

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking to load the List with ANY SUPER Class of Integer.
Object is the only class that Super of Integer.

Number is an Object hence it is legal to write `new ArrayList<Number>()`;

But when you try to get from numbersList, It could only be an Object.
Because Object is the only Super class of Integer.

Let me know if you have any doubt, or if you think I need to correct my understanding.

Regards,
Venod

Comment: I think he didn't consider `Number` as it an `abstract class` ;)

Comment: @Venod The error is not because Number is abstract. The error is because of the reasons that the other answers explained.

Comment: Well, that's definitely wrong because **Object is the only super class of Integer**